# How to change text in confirmationUrl in FosUserBundle email?

Tags: php, symfony, email, twig, fosuserbundle

When is sending e-mail, receiver have in anchor text element: "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/iii/index.php/admin/resetting/reset/vJmLaAAhPADTikpRde_4Q40GBNN9r43dlMEunm_3Byo". I want a custom text like "[click here](http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/iii/index.php/admin/resetting/reset/vJmLaAAhPADTikpRde_4Q40GBNN9r43dlMEunm_3Byo)"

I tried by override by file: templates/FOSUserBundle/emal.html.twig (with configuration in config/packages/fos_user.yml)

```
{% block body_html %}
{{ confirmationUrl}}
{% autoescape false %}

<p>
Please confirm your registration by visiting <a href="{{ confirmationUrl|raw }}">here</a>
</p>
```

Sent e-mail looks:

http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/iii/index.php/admin/resetting/reset/vJmLaAAhPADTikpRde_4Q40GBNN9r43dlMEunm_3Byo

```
<p>
 Please confirm your registration by visiting <a href="#"  target="_blank" rel="noopener" disabled="disabled" aria-disabled="true">here</a>
</p>
```

I have problems: why doesnt display "here" but all link and why does display html tags. Anybody have idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: So your question is how to override a fosuserbundle twig file ?

Comment: @L01C no - it works. I only need to change text in confirmationUrl